# Sharing dependancies in Symfony services without passing parameters to sub classes

Tags: php, symfony

A lot of my services rely on a PDO connection to an external database (for reasons specific to my application, it made sense to use this strategy over using Doctrine). To start a PDO connection, each services needs a data source name, username and password. This leaves my `services.yml` containing much of the same arguments for each service:

```
#AppBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

    # ...

    QueryDataBuilderHelper:
        class: AppBundle\Services\QueryDataBuilderHelper
        arguments: [ "%database_host%", "%database_user%", "%database_password%" ]

    ZipCodeClass:
        class: AppBundle\Services\ZipCodeClass
        arguments: [ "%database_host%", "%database_user%", "%database_password%" ]

    # ...
```

**Is it possible to define the connection somewhere and reference it in all services without passing parameters to each one?**

The [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html) recommends using parent services and extending the parent services. When I try to use the subclass, the subclass doesn't pull the arguments of the superclass:

```
#AppBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

DBConnectionHelper:
    class: AppBundle\Services\DBConnectionHelper
    arguments: [ "%database_host%", "%database_user%", "%database_password%" ]


DBSubClass:
    class: AppBundle\Services\DBSubClass
    parent: DBConnectionHelper
    arguments: [ "%unrelated_parameter%" ]
```

---

```
//AppBundle\Services\SuperClassService.php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

class DBConnectionHelper
{
    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $password){
        $this->DB_connection = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    }
}
```

---

```
//AppBundle\Services\DBSubClass.php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

class DBSubClass extends DBConnectionHelper
{
    public function __construct($unrelated_param){
        //Calling parent::__construct() here will require the parameters again. 
        //Which is what I am trying to avoid...

        // Outputs a notice that DB_Connection isn't set.
        var_dump($this->DB_Connection());

        $this->unrelated_param = $unrelated_param;
    }
}
```

I've used the constructor here instead of setters because these dependancies are not optional. The [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection) suggest that setters should only be used when dependancies are optional.

Comment: Inject `DBConnectionHelper` into other services: `arguments: [@DBConnectionHelper]`

Comment: @malcolm, That's certainly an improvement! But, I can't help but feel that there should be a better solution that _explicitly_ extends from a superclass.

Comment: Just define your connection as a service and inject it.  I don't see the problem here.  You probably want to use a pdo factory service but that should not be a big deal.  I think you may be misunderstanding the desirability of "parent services".  No need for them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to use here is called an `Abstract Service`. Luckily for you, Symfony is providing a way to achieve this. The options you're looking for are `abstract` and `parent`. You can read the entire chapter [here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html)

I will try to briefly explain the example from documentation, so that you can grasp the idea.

```
# ...
services:
    # ...
    mail_manager:
        abstract:  true
        calls:
            - [setMailer, ["@my_mailer"]]
            - [setEmailFormatter, ["@my_email_formatter"]]

    newsletter_manager:
        class:  "NewsletterManager"
        parent: mail_manager

    greeting_card_manager:
        class:  "GreetingCardManager"
        parent: mail_manager
```

Basically what you need to do is this:

- Create an abstract class where you will define all common properties/methods.
- Then configure these common method calls in your service file accordingly and add the option `abstract`. Since your service is an `abstract` one it means that it cannot be instantiated, so `class` option here is omitted.
- After that create a service like you always do, and don't forget to `extend` the abstract class. Then register that service in your `service.yml` file and add the `parent` option to it, by setting the name of your abstract service.
- Repeat the step above as many times as you wish for each child service and you should be good to go.

If you have any questions, leave a comment. Hope this can help you out.

Comment: Upvote for an interesting approach to this issue. I didn't know symfony was capable of doing such cool abstraction in the services! Thanks for pointing this out. I believe this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: Yes, it's really good one! I use this approach for creating a mailer component system, where each child service generate it's own unique content and pass it to the parent where I create my `Mailer` once with all its needed options. Glad you like it.

Comment: I hit a snag when trying this and thought I should comment about it for future googlers: It's not possible to reference variables set by the parent's calls in the sub-service's constructor - because the sub-service's constructor is called before the parent's calls are.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than extend your DBConnectionHelper class, you could inject it as a dependancy via your constructor.

```
//AppBundle\Services\DBSubClass.php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

class DBSubClass
{
    private $dbConnectionHelper;

    public function __construct($dbConnectionHelper, $unrelated_param)
    {
        $this->dbConnectionHelper = $dbConnectionHelper;
        $this->unrelated_param = $unrelated_param;
    }
}
```

You can then get your connection using `$this->dbConnectionHelper->DB_Connection()`.

You would also need to configure your service as:

```
DBSubClass:
    class: AppBundle\Services\DBSubClass
    arguments: [ "@DBConnectionHelper", "%unrelated_parameter%" ]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment, this is very big improvement. But I feel like there should be a more explicit way of extending from a super class. I'll accept this answer in a day or so if there aren't any other answers that address that.

Comment: If you wish to extend DBConnectionHelper then it needs to be instantiated by the constructor, which means passing the necessary variables for this to happen. Using dependency injection passes an already instantiated object. A way to pass the parameters efficiently may be to put them in an array.

Comment: Whether you use this method or that of an abstract parent class probably depends on how many instances of the parent class you require. Using an abstract parent class creates a new instance each time it is used. If you require only one instance of the "parent" class, such as a database connection, then injecting this one instance seems the way to go.